# C error message: "Reading invalid data from ***** : the readable size is '28' bytes, but '32' bytes may be read."

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

The code below is just snippet from my real code. I have a binary tree and get nodes to insert.
I have to do something with the node inserted and the 3 predecessor und 3 successor nodes.
If a node is not found searchNode returns NULL. I want to prevent searching 7 nodes over and over again. So i thought about shifting them for the difference in key value compared to the previous key value, if they are close enough.

The gcc compiler gives me this warning:

`"Reading invalid data from 'scope': the readable size is '28' bytes, but '32' bytes may be read."`

on that code line: `scope[k] = scope[k + diff];`. I guess its because scope[k + diff] might be outside of the defined range, but i dont see it happening with the above if-statement.

```
struct Node
{
    long key;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
    int height;
};

struct Node* searchNode(struct Node* root, long key)
{

    if (root == NULL || root->key == key) {
        return root;
    }
    if (key < root->key)
        return searchNode(root->left, key);
    else
        return searchNode(root->right, key);
}

int main(){

    struct Node* scope[7];
    int flag1 = 0;
    int preKey = 0;
    int diff = 0;
    int xKey = 0;
    struct Node* temp = NULL;
    
    // Node inserted
    temp = searchNode(tree, xKey);

    if (flag1 == 0) { //for the first element checked
        flag1 = 1;
    SCOPE:;
        preKey = temp->key;
        scope[0] = searchNode(tree, xKey - 3);
        scope[1] = searchNode(tree, xKey - 2);
        scope[2] = searchNode(tree, xKey - 1);
        scope[3] = temp;
        scope[4] = searchNode(tree, xKey + 1);
        scope[5] = searchNode(tree, xKey + 2);
        scope[6] = searchNode(tree, xKey + 3);
    }
    else {
        diff = temp->key - preKey;
        if (diff > 6)
            goto SCOPE;
        else {
            for (int k = 0; k < 7 - diff; k++) {
                scope[k] = scope[k + diff];
            }
            for (int j = 7 - diff; j < 7; j++) {
                scope[j] = searchNode(tree, temp->key + j - 3);
            }
            preKey = temp->key;
        }
    }             
}
```

Comment: The `goto SCOPE` there makes my head hurt. Consider rewriting without the goto so it's more readable and less fragile.

Comment: @calculuswhiz the new versions of gcc can range check areays at compile time. Werror for an error

Comment: @dekrion where are you checking that the difference is not negative for example..

Comment: It will be helpful if you put an example of `tree` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The line in question is:

```
scope[k] = scope[k + diff];
```

Given the if statement, the compiler can deduce that when executing that line, diff ≤ 6, but diff may also be any negative number. So diff is in { -∞ .. 6 }.
And it can know that k is in the range { 0 .. 12 }, inclusive.
That means that k + diff must be in the range { -∞ .. 18 }.
But scope only goes from 0 to 7.
So it's quite possible that you will be attempting to read from an address that is not allocated.